# Competition question - Proportion

Tags: contest-math

I have this contest question that I don't quite get how to solve.

At 10 am, the school flagpole cast a shadow *6m* long. Next to the flagpole, the *0.5m* high water tap cast a shadow *0.3m* long.
How tall is the flagpole in metres.

I have tried using proportion:

If a *0.3m* long shadow was created by an object *0.5m* high,
Then a *6m* long shadow will be created by an object *10m* high.

This is assuming that the constant of proportionality is 1 and 2 thirds.

However, I don't think this is a good way to solve this problem and nor do I think the answer is correct,
is there any way to solve this in a more structured way?

Comment: Are you thinking about similar triangles?

Comment: Not exactly, I was thinking more on direct proportion and rates.

Comment: Draw a picture.  You'll see two similar triangles.  That justifies using proportion.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: "I don't think this is a good way to solve this problem and nor do I think the answer is correct," Why on earth not?!  It's a law of the universe and we can assume without question that Height:: shadow is at any time and place a constant proportion and as we *have* height and shdaow pair (0.5 water tap with 0.3 shadow ) we *know* the proportion is $0.5$ to $0.3$ or $5$ to $3$.  So we know $FLAGPOLE::6 = 5::3$.  Or  in other words $\frac x6 = \frac 53$.   It's very simple and correct to solve $x = 10$.

Comment: Thank you for the thought, I am sometimes completely unsure on my answers and my method!

Comment: Are there any other ways to solve this problem, preferably using algebra?